# Extract letters based on increment

Tags: r

I have two variables a and b

```
a             b
asdsafd       3
gsdfgasdsa    4
```

I want to extract letters from the variable "a" based on the value of "b" with increment of 2 to next two character using r programming

```
output
c
af
as
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `substring`

```
c <- substring(df2$a, df2$b+2, df2$b+3)
c 
#[1] "af" "as"
output <- data.frame(c, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Why it is +2 and +3. What if i have more than 1000 records

Comment: @63549 It is based on the example and expected output you provided.  You `+2` will make sure that it does the `increment of 2` with the 'b' values.  As you are looking for next two characters, I used `+3`.  If you have 1000 records also it will work assuming that the description you mentioned is correct.  If you have a different description, sorry it will not work.